# Divergence in prices

Tags: magento2, price

I have an observer who changes the price of the items and at the end of the routine the whole order changes, but on my cart edit screen the subtotal of the item still keeps the old price of the item, how can I fix this?

The functions used to make the change are:

```
$itemcarrinho->setCustomPrice($temp);                                        
$itemcarrinho->setOriginalCustomPrice($temp);                                     
$itemcarrinho->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$itemcarrinho->save();

$quote->setSubtotal($total)
->setBaseSubtotal($total)
->setGrandTotal($total)
->setBaseGrandTotal($total);
$quote->save();
```

[image]

Magento 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I had to change the price also by line by function:

```
$item->setRowTotal($item->getCustomPrice() * $item->getQty());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear checkout session storage in your observer before you save the quote.

See for code reference - `\Magento\Checkout\Observer\UnsetAllObserver::execute()`